# Azure Devops Pull Requests - stop all employees appearing in PR reviewer dropdown

Tags: azure-devops

I'm looking to migrate our git repos from Bitbucket to Azure Devops.

However, one issue I've found when doing this is that in Azure Devops, when you create a pull request and go to select the reviewers, the drop-down autocomplete offers you the name of everyone in Active Directory, which contains everyone from the CEO to Marketing and all else.

Obviously I want that list to be restricted to just the development team. I think I've configured the team project correctly so that only the dev team have access to it, so how do I get it to restrict the drop-down accordingly?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

> how do I get it to restrict the drop-down accordingly?

I am afraid there is no such way to restrict the drop-down accordingly at this moment.

As I know, the reviewers in the dropdown list only shows the team group or user you are recently specified (ordered by time and it’s not default reviewers).This is to make it more convenient for us to choose reviewers without having to manually enter each time.

So the essence of this question is how to restrict Active Directory people as reviewers.

But Azure devops does not have this feature at present.

To get this feature, you could add your request for this feature on our UserVoice site (https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/content/idea/post.html?space=21 ), which is our main forum for product suggestions. Thank you for helping us build a better Azure DevOps.

[image]